# Winrar SFX command line ignoring -iicon switch

Tags: windows-7, cmd, winrar, ico, sfx

I am trying to create a winrar self-extracting archive with a custom icon on the command line.

It is all going well so far, except the custom icon is not working. Whenever I build the archive the icon used is the default winrar icon.

If I create the SFX using the SFX dialog, then **it works fine**. This says to me that there is nothing wrong with the icon.

The command I am using is:

```
rar a -r -ep1 -sfx -iiconC:\AMC\setupicons\setup.ico -z"Source\createrarsetups.conf" setup.exe "SetupFiles\*"
```

Answer (score 2):

The text file `Rar.txt` in program files folder of *WinRAR* contains all commands and switches supported by console version `Rar.exe`. Running `Rar.exe` without any parameter lists also all of them with a brief description.

The commands and switches supported by `WinRAR.exe` are explained in help of *WinRAR*, open on help tab **Contents** the item **Command line mode**.

There are a few differences in list of supported switches between console and GUI version. One of those few differences is no support by console version for SFX icon. I suppose, the reason is the need of a Microsoft library function not (easily) available for a console application.

You can use `WinRAR.exe` instead of `Rar.exe` even when running it from within a batch file.  Use additionally the switches`-ibck` and `-inul` to run `WinRAR.exe` in background without displaying an error message on failure. Switch `-y` might be also useful.

```
"%ProgramFiles%\WinRAR\WinRAR.exe" a -r -ep1 -inul -ibck -y -sfx -iiconC:\AMC\setupicons\setup.ico -z"Source\createrarsetups.conf" setup.exe "SetupFiles\*"
if errorlevel 1 echo There was an error on creating the SFX archive!
```

Comment: Using WinRAR.exe instead of Rar.exe really works, but, for some reason, I also needed to change the name of the generated file for the icon to appear. After I managed to generate the sfx with the icon, I switched back to the original name I wanted for the exe and it also worked.

Comment: Winrar doesn't complaint if the icon path doesn't exists, it just uses the default one. 
I delete the output exe on every try. 
Somehow Winrar stores something (maybe as cache), unless I change the output file name, I would not get the icon anymore. Switching back and forth didn't work, I have a filename that can't have icon anymore :D

Answer (score 0):

For a workaround

```
rar a -r -ep1 -sfx -z"Source\createrarsetups.conf" setup.exe "SetupFiles\*"
winrar s -iiconC:\AMC\setupicons\setup.ico setup.exe
```

You can also make it work using only one command but calling `winrar` instead of `rar`. And no, i don't know why the console version does not include the icon.